# Error handling in Azure function when used with SendGrid as output binding

Tags: azure, azure-functions, sendgrid

I have a C# Azure function with output binding to SendGrid.
This Azure Function gets triggered when a message arrives in a ServiceBus topic. I operate on message and finally returns SendGridMessage. Hereon, SendGrid is responsible for sending out the actual email.

But in this whole scenario, Azure function does not get to know if the email is delivered or failed. Is there any way or hook available which can give me the aforementioned details ?

Any links, examples are appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there is a way using the Sendgrid binding, as all the sending logic is abstracted away. If you need that, however, it's not much more complicated to instantiate your own Sendgrid client inside your Function:

```
using SendGrid;
using SendGrid.Helpers.Mail;

static SendGridClient _sendGridClient = new SendGridClient(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SendgridApiKey"]);

var msg = MailHelper.CreateSingleEmail(from, to, subject, plainTextContent, htmlContent);
var result = await _sendGridClient.SendEmailAsync(msg);
log.LogDebug($"SendGrid result={result.Body}");
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Here, what i understand about Service bus  is, a message is sent to dead-letter queue under 3 conditions: 1. On Exceeding MaxDeliveryCount 2. Exceeding TimeToLive and 3. On Filter evaluation Error. Among these 3 i have understood first 2, but couldn't understand 3rd. If possible can share light on 3rd one ? Is it any way related to error/exceptions in output binding (in my case SendGrid)

Comment: Again, everything in the SendGrid binding is abstracted away from you. So you cannot react to exceptions etc. which might occur therein. Thus, you can also not influence any behavior of your incoming messages.

Comment: Oh ! if such is the case, it's difficult to be assure that emails are delivered if we are using Sendgrid output binding. Thanks for the help.

Comment: That’s why I’m suggesting in my answer to use the Sendgrid SDK directly in your function

Comment: yes, that is one way out. But I am trying to understand whether AZURE infrastructure does a retry when there is SendGrid binding failure ?

Comment: Well that’s the advantage of it all being open source  you can see what’s happening behind the scenes https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-extensions/tree/master/src/WebJobs.Extensions.SendGrid

Comment: And looking at the code, I’d say the answer is No to any retrying.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, yeah looking at https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-extensions/blob/master/src/WebJobs.Extensions.SendGrid/Client/SendGridClient.cs this, there is no retrying, but I am asking about AZURE service bus retry, meaning if there is ouput binding error with SendGrid, will service bus resend that message to my azure function ?

Comment: The input binding (in your case service bus) and output binding (sendgrid) are seperate. So no, there is no interaction between them.

Comment: Thanks so much @silent. Really appreciated your time and efforts.

Comment: you're welcome. Please accept the answer if the topic is closed for you.